# grammatically - what's wrong with these sentences

Tags: grammar

The sentence does not make sense, but it does have a subject and a predicate. So what is grammatically wrong with it?

We felt the cats that she had on her house.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. If I am reading this correctly, you mean that since it seems like nonsense that it should not be considered grammatical?

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with the grammar!!!

Comment: Remember, "We ate the floor of the barn" is perfectly good grammar, even if it is poor taste.

Comment: Please identify what you think is wrong. It makes perfect sense to me: e.g. *We climbed onto the roof of her house and felt each of the cats that she had chained there: they were all alive, but in poor health.*

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, and loving the pun ;-)

Comment: @Chappo - Or "We felt the cats that she had on her house were in danger of falling off."

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything incorrect about the sentence in reference to grammar.

We = subject
felt = verb 
that = connector
she = subject
had = verb
on = preposition
her = possessive adjective
house = object of the preposition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a more specific verb instead of had? I had to read the sentence twice and it would have been easier to grasp its meaning with more information.
For example:
We felt the cats' fur that she had placed on her house.
We felt the presence of the cats that she had on her roof.

If you meant to be confusing, well done.